# ¿Existe algún evento que pueda detectar si se da clic en cualquier apartado de la barra del navegador?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existe la forma en la cual pueda detectar un evento si se da clic en la barra del navegador.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo más probable es que si exista un evento, pero eso se controla a nivel de la programación del navegador, lo cual esta fuera del alcance de lo que interpreta, ya sean html , javascript o lo que sea que interprete el navegador.

Answer (score 2):

Lamentablemente no existe algún evento en JS o jQuery el cual te puede detectar si el usuario hizo click en cualquier parte de la barra del navegador.

Saludos,
JB